# Extracting values from a function

Tags: matlab

I have a loop within a function that spits out values similar to:

E = 3,2,1,-1,-2

for

i = 1,2,3,4,5

I'm trying to extract the position where E becomes negative and then identify the step before it.

My attempt was something like
finalPos = find(i(E<0));

Firstly, it just doesn't seem right (my matlab syntax knowledge is poor as)
but secondly even if it did work it would tell me all positions where E is less than 0, where I only want to know the position before where E is no longer positive. i.e. E = 1, i = 3

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us a [mcve], it sounds like you just want `find( E < 0, 1 ) - 1 )` which returns one less than the first index where `E` is negative, but this question is currently unclear and perfectly suited to a proper example

Comment: Assuming `E` are `i` are vectors, you can use `i(find(E < 0, 1, 'first') - 1)` to get the index of the value right before the first negative value in `E`. If the first value in `E` is negative, this will fail, of course. So, maybe add a special case for that.

Comment: @Hans `'first'` is the default behaviour, so that suggestion is the same as mine (when `i = [1 2 3 ...]` as given)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below:

```
E = [3,2,1,-1,-2] ;


idx = find(sign(E)==-1)  % Get the sign and get index
idx = find(E<0)          % Get by value

for i = 1:length(E)
    if sign(E(i)) == -1
        fprintf('E is Negative\n')
    else
        fprintf('E is Positive\n')
    end
end
```

Comment: The loop here makes the answer much more complicated than it is, as it doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

For last positive value 
you can use a variable to store the last value

Example:-

```
E=[3,2,1,-1,-2]

finalpos=-1  


for i = 1:5
  if ( E<0)
    finalpos=E(i-1);
    break;
  end
end

finalpos
```